# Paid decryption scheme and possible attack surface

Tags: ransomware

This is how ransomware can work as far as I understand:

Most ransomware works with symmetric encryption on individual files. For each file the script generates a new key. A list is then generated containing all the file-paths with their respective keys.

This list is then asymmetrically encrypted. The victim has to pay for the private key to decrypt the master list.

The malware then reads the list to unlock all the files.

Is knowledge of part of this list (all the file-paths) helpful in finding the private key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Knowing parts of the plaintext is commonly considered as one of the [attackers capabilities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chosen-plaintext_attack) when attacking a cryptographic scheme. So all the widely used schemes are resilient to that.

That means that for decent asymmetric encryption it will not help you.